# Iterate over JSON string with Bash

Tags: json, bash

I'm building a script to process JSON for specifc Chef/node data. I need to get the name of each object as it will be different every time. Typically I use jsawk but this is only helpful if you know the name of the object.

A solution should work on either of the below examples:

```
{"keepalived":{"role":"MASTER","vip":"192.168.4.113"},"mysql":{"service_name":"singularitydb"},"haproxy":{"role":"MASTER"}}
```

Should return: keepalived,mysql,haproxy

```
{"nginx":{"attribute":"standalone"},"haproxy":{"role":"MASTER"}}
```

Should return: nginx,haproxy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `jq`:

```
echo "$JSON" | jq 'keys'
```

Comment: it won't work for objects inside objects, but maybe author doesn't need that

Comment: Neither example indicates that is required. Both ask for the top-level keys of  an object.

Comment: I'll give it to you for introducing me to jq...but i really wanted to iterate over the keys. Did it with this: `jslength=$(echo $attributes | jq 'keys | length')
 for ((i=0; i<$jslength; i++)); do
  result=$(echo $attributes | jq 'keys' | jq ".[$i]")
  echo $result
 done`

Comment: You should be clearer about what you ask for: `echo "$attributes" | jq 'keys | .[]'` is the equivalent of the code in your comment. Depending on what you actually want to *do* with each key while iterating, there may also be something in `jq` you can use.